# Devise UninitializedConstant ApplicationController with controllers in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to consolidate one of my apps to controllers and views into sub folders - one for the marketing site, and one for the app itself.

This is what I currently have:

```
app/controllers
  application_controller.rb
  ...shit ton of other controllers...
```

This is what i'm going for:

```
app/controllers/app
  application_controller.rb
  ...all controllers related to the app itself...

app/controllers/marketing
  ...all controllers related to the marketing site...
```

Marketing site works just fine because there is no authentication necessary, but the app is bombing out b/c devise doesn't know that application_controller.rb is now in `app/controllers/app/application_controller.rb`

How can I tell devise about the location of my controller?

Here's my devise routes:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
      as :user do
        get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
        post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
        delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
        get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
      end
```

Part of the stacktrace:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant ApplicationController:
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:520:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
  devise (2.2.4) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  devise (2.2.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:80:in `devise_controller?'
  devise (2.2.4) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:48:in `authenticate_user!'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @benchwarmer said, if you do put a controller in a subdirectory, you'll need to namespace the class name accordingly; `App::ApplicationController` in your case.  However, it seems you'd then need to make all your existing controllers inherit from `App::ApplicationController` instead of `ApplicationController`.  Why not keep `ApplicationController` at the top level and if you need additional methods for the main app or the marketing app, create, for example, a `Marketing::MarketingController` in `marketing/` which extends `ApplicationController` and which all controllers in marketing can then extend, and similarly for the app directory.  Alternatively, you could just put your marketing controllers in a marketing subdirectory and Marketing:: namespace, and leave your app controllers in `controllers/` instead of having a separate subdirectory for them.  Anyway, up to you.  The other piece of the puzzle is that if you move the ApplicationController (or want devise to inherit from any arbitrary controller), you'll need to add to your `devise.rb` initialiser:

```
config.parent_controller = "App::ApplicationController"
```

in your case if you move the application controller into an app/ subdirectory and namespace it.  This tells devise which controller its controllers should inherit from and it defaults to `ApplicationController` which is why it can't find it when you've moved it.

Comment: config.parent_controller made it work. I will probably take both of your advise and have each controller inherit from 1 application_controller. How did you find out about config.parent_controller?

Comment: I honestly can't remember how I found out about parent_controller.  It might have been by looking at the source for DeviseController.  It's a shame it isn't included in commented-out form in the generated devise.rb when devise is installed in an app as that would make it more obvious.  Perhaps one of us should submit a pull request :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not move the `application_controller.rb` file from its original location, keep it on its original location. As far as naming class of the file `app/controller/app/application_controller.rb` it should be

```
class App::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

and other controllers under this directory inherits from `App::ApplicationController` class